# Snap.svg: Intermittent animation error

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I been trying to find what's causing an error in the example below. The error happens periodically. What happens is that when a button is clicked to animate its rotation and the associated symbols, sometimes the requested animation incorrectly scales the symbols: They become scaled upward. The symbol(s) that the error occurs is also not consistent.

You may have to run the code snippet a few times before you experience the error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title> Animate Polygon Sprites</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svgDiscovery.com/_SNP/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
        content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4>Animate Polygon Sprites</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
There are 30 sprites in the &lt;defs>.
Each  sprite is comprised of a &lt;g> element containing polygons created with their centers at (0,0) and sized at 1 pixel.
 Therefore they can be seamlessly transformed, making them ideal for animations.

</div>
 <center><b>Click on a button to rotate its sprite and the associated symbols</b></center>

<table ><tr>
<td valign=top>

<div style=width:100px;height:500px;overflow:auto>
<table border=1 style=width:50px; id=spriteTable></table>
</div>
</td>
<td align=center>
<div id="svgDiv" style='width:400px;height:400px;background:lightgreen'>
<svg id=mySVG width=400 height=400>
<defs id=spriteDefs><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g size="1" id="Star4"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.176777,0.176777 0.5,2.98023e-008 0.176777,-0.176777 2.98023e-008,-0.5 -0.176777,-0.176777 -0.5,2.98023e-008 -0.176777,0.176777 2.98023e-008,0.5" /></g><g size="1" id="Star5"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.25,0.131433 0.5,-0.112257 0.154508,-0.16246 -1.6888e-008,-0.475527 -0.154508,-0.16246 -0.5,-0.112257 -0.25,0.131433 -0.309017,0.475527 -1.6888e-008,0.313068 0.309017,0.475527" /></g><g size="1" id="Star6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.216506,0.125 0.5,2.98023e-008 0.216506,-0.125 0.25,-0.433013 2.98023e-008,-0.25 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.216506,-0.125 -0.5,2.98023e-008 -0.216506,0.125 -0.25,0.433013 2.98023e-008,0.25 0.25,0.433013" /></g><g size="1" id="Star10"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.146946,0.202254 0.40451,0.293893 0.237764,0.0772543 0.5,2.98023e-008 0.237764,-0.0772543 0.40451,-0.293893 0.146946,-0.202254 0.154509,-0.475527 2.98023e-008,-0.25 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.146946,-0.202254 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.237764,-0.0772543 -0.5,2.98023e-008 -0.237764,0.0772543 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.146946,0.202254 -0.154508,0.475527 2.98023e-008,0.25 0.154509,0.475527" /></g><g size="1" id="Star15"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.102244,0.235138 0.295511,0.41223 0.18681,0.173697 0.435397,0.25687 0.239074,0.083173 0.5,0.0580453 0.25,-0.0207829 0.478147,-0.149866 0.217699,-0.120195 0.37362,-0.330915 0.147756,-0.197875 0.204488,-0.453797 0.0522643,-0.240391 -3.67563e-008,-0.49726 -0.0522643,-0.240391 -0.204489,-0.453797 -0.147756,-0.197875 -0.37362,-0.330915 -0.217699,-0.120195 -0.478147,-0.149866 -0.25,-0.0207829 -0.5,0.0580453 -0.239074,0.083173 -0.435397,0.25687 -0.18681,0.173697 -0.295512,0.41223 -0.102244,0.235138 -0.104528,0.49726 -3.67563e-008,0.25687 0.104528,0.49726" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4d"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,-0.5 -0.5,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,0.5" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.96047e-008 0.25,-0.433013 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.5,5.96047e-008 -0.25,0.433013 0.25,0.433013" /></g><g size="1" id="RhombHoriz"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="-2.1855e-007,-0.288675 -0.5,-2.1855e-007 -2.1855e-007,0.288675 0.5,-2.1855e-007" /></g><g size="1" id="RhombVert"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="-2.1855e-007,-0.5 -0.288675,-2.1855e-007 -2.1855e-007,0.5 0.288675,-2.1855e-007" /></g><g size="1" id="CircleStar6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-4.5697e-008 0.475527,-0.154509 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154508,-0.47553 -4.5697e-008,-0.5 -0.154509,-0.47553 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.47553,-0.154509 -0.5,-4.5697e-008 -0.47553,0.154508 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154509,0.475527 -4.5697e-008,0.5 0.154508,0.475527 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.475527,0.154508" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.20773,0.119933 0.479733,-4.5697e-008 0.20773,-0.119933 0.239866,-0.41546 -4.5697e-008,-0.239866 -0.239866,-0.41546 -0.20773,-0.119933 -0.479733,-4.5697e-008 -0.20773,0.119933 -0.239866,0.41546 -4.5697e-008,0.239866 0.239866,0.41546" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4vStar6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,-0.5 -0.5,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,0.5" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.171464,0.0989947 0.39598,-1.47025e-007 0.171464,-0.098995 0.19799,-0.34293 -1.47025e-007,-0.19799 -0.19799,-0.34293 -0.171464,-0.098995 -0.39598,-1.47025e-007 -0.171464,0.0989947 -0.19799,0.34293 -1.47025e-007,0.19799 0.19799,0.34293" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4Star6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.48077,0.48077 0.48077,-0.48077 -0.48077,-0.48077 -0.48077,0.48077" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.216506,0.125 0.5,3.57627e-008 0.216506,-0.125 0.25,-0.433013 3.57627e-008,-0.25 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.216506,-0.125 -0.5,3.57627e-008 -0.216506,0.125 -0.25,0.433013 3.57627e-008,0.25 0.25,0.433013" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4dCircle"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-1.49012e-008 -1.49012e-008,-0.5 -0.5,-1.49012e-008 -1.49012e-008,0.5" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.282509,-1.49012e-008 0.268682,-0.0873 0.228555,-0.166055 0.166055,-0.228555 0.0873,-0.268682 -1.49012e-008,-0.282509 -0.0873,-0.268682 -0.166055,-0.228555 -0.228555,-0.166055 -0.268682,-0.0873 -0.282509,-1.49012e-008 -0.268682,0.0873 -0.228555,0.166055 -0.166055,0.228555 -0.0873,0.268682 -1.49012e-008,0.282509 0.0873,0.268682 0.166055,0.228555 0.228555,0.166055 0.268682,0.0873" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4vRhombHoriz"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,-0.5 -0.5,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,0.5" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-1.47025e-007,-0.282843 -0.489897,-1.47025e-007 -1.47025e-007,0.282843 0.489897,-1.47025e-007" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4vRhombVert"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-1.82788e-007 -1.82788e-007,-0.5 -0.5,-1.82788e-007 -1.82788e-007,0.5" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-1.82788e-007,-0.45928 -0.265165,-1.82788e-007 -1.82788e-007,0.45928 0.265165,-1.82788e-007" /></g><g size="1" id="CircleRhombHoriz"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="5.16573e-008,-0.260724 -0.451587,5.16573e-008 5.16573e-008,0.260724 0.451587,5.16573e-008" /></g><g size="1" id="CircleRhombVert"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="5.16573e-008,-0.451587 -0.260724,5.16573e-008 5.16573e-008,0.451587 0.260724,5.16573e-008" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon3r"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.421483,5.16573e-008 -0.210741,-0.365013 -0.210741,0.365013" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon3t"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.365013,0.210741 5.16573e-008,-0.42148 -0.365013,0.210741" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon3l"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.210741,0.365013 0.210741,-0.365013 -0.42148,5.16573e-008" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon3b"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="5.16573e-008,0.421483 0.365013,-0.210741 -0.365013,-0.210741" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon4d"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.442463,5.16573e-008 5.16573e-008,-0.442463 -0.442463,5.16573e-008 5.16573e-008,0.442463" /></g><g size="1" id="CircleEllipseVert"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-9.23873e-008 0.475527,-0.154509 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154508,-0.47553 -9.23873e-008,-0.5 -0.154509,-0.47553 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.47553,-0.154509 -0.5,-9.23873e-008 -0.47553,0.154508 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154509,0.475527 -9.23873e-008,0.5 0.154508,0.475527 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.475527,0.154508" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.1875,-9.23873e-008 0.178323,-0.115881 0.151691,-0.22042 0.11021,-0.303382 0.0579407,-0.356647 -9.23873e-008,-0.375 -0.0579407,-0.356647 -0.11021,-0.303382 -0.151691,-0.22042 -0.178323,-0.115881 -0.1875,-9.23873e-008 -0.178323,0.115881 -0.151691,0.220419 -0.11021,0.303381 -0.0579407,0.356647 -9.23873e-008,0.375 0.0579407,0.356647 0.11021,0.303381 0.151691,0.220419 0.178323,0.115881" /></g><g size="1" id="CircleEllipseHoriz"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.4,5.16573e-008 0.380423,-0.0618033 0.323607,-0.117557 0.235114,-0.161803 0.123607,-0.190211 5.16573e-008,-0.2 -0.123607,-0.190211 -0.235114,-0.161803 -0.323607,-0.117557 -0.380423,-0.0618033 -0.4,5.16573e-008 -0.380423,0.0618033 -0.323607,0.117557 -0.235114,0.161803 -0.123607,0.190211 5.16573e-008,0.2 0.123607,0.190211 0.235114,0.161803 0.323607,0.117557 0.380423,0.0618033" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4Circle"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.383547,5.96047e-008 0.364777,-0.118523 0.310296,-0.225443 0.225443,-0.310296 0.118523,-0.364777 5.96047e-008,-0.383547 -0.118523,-0.364777 -0.225443,-0.310296 -0.310296,-0.225443 -0.364777,-0.118523 -0.383547,5.96047e-008 -0.364777,0.118523 -0.310296,0.225443 -0.225443,0.310296 -0.118523,0.364777 5.96047e-008,0.383547 0.118523,0.364777 0.225443,0.310296 0.310296,0.225443 0.364777,0.118523" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon4"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-6.15913e-008 0.475527,-0.154509 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154508,-0.475527 -6.15913e-008,-0.5 -0.154509,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154509 -0.5,-6.15913e-008 -0.475527,0.154508 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154509,0.475527 -6.15913e-008,0.5 0.154508,0.475527 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.475527,0.154508" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.312869,0.312869 0.312869,-0.312869 -0.312869,-0.312869 -0.312869,0.312869" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon6Circle"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.96047e-008 0.25,-0.433013 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.5,5.96047e-008 -0.25,0.433013 0.25,0.433013" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.319623,5.96047e-008 0.303979,-0.0987687 0.25858,-0.187869 0.187869,-0.25858 0.0987687,-0.303979 5.96047e-008,-0.319623 -0.0987687,-0.303979 -0.187869,-0.25858 -0.25858,-0.187869 -0.303979,-0.0987687 -0.319623,5.96047e-008 -0.303979,0.0987687 -0.25858,0.187869 -0.187869,0.25858 -0.0987687,0.303979 5.96047e-008,0.319623 0.0987687,0.303979 0.187869,0.25858 0.25858,0.187869 0.303979,0.0987687" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon4CircleStar5"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.383547,5.96047e-008 0.364777,-0.118523 0.310296,-0.225443 0.225443,-0.310296 0.118523,-0.364777 5.96047e-008,-0.383547 -0.118523,-0.364777 -0.225443,-0.310296 -0.310296,-0.225443 -0.364777,-0.118523 -0.383547,5.96047e-008 -0.364777,0.118523 -0.310296,0.225443 -0.225443,0.310296 -0.118523,0.364777 5.96047e-008,0.383547 0.118523,0.364777 0.225443,0.310296 0.310296,0.225443 0.364777,0.118523" /><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.152169,0.0494427 0.304338,-0.0988853 0.0940457,-0.129443 5.96047e-008,-0.32 -0.0940457,-0.129443 -0.304338,-0.0988853 -0.152169,0.0494427 -0.188091,0.258886 5.96047e-008,0.16 0.188091,0.258886" /></g><g size="1" id="CirclePgon4vStar6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,5.16573e-008 0.47553,-0.154508 0.40451,-0.293893 0.293893,-0.40451 0.154509,-0.475527 5.16573e-008,-0.5 -0.154508,-0.475527 -0.293893,-0.40451 -0.40451,-0.293893 -0.475527,-0.154508 -0.5,5.16573e-008 -0.475527,0.154509 -0.40451,0.293893 -0.293893,0.40451 -0.154508,0.47553 5.16573e-008,0.5 0.154509,0.47553 0.293893,0.40451 0.40451,0.293893 0.47553,0.154509" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.442463,5.16573e-008 5.16573e-008,-0.442463 -0.442463,5.16573e-008 5.16573e-008,0.442463" /><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.135476,0.0782173 0.312869,5.16573e-008 0.135476,-0.0782173 0.156435,-0.270952 5.16573e-008,-0.156434 -0.156434,-0.270952 -0.135476,-0.0782173 -0.312869,5.16573e-008 -0.135476,0.0782173 -0.156434,0.270952 5.16573e-008,0.156435 0.156435,0.270952" /></g><g size="1" id="Star6Circle"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.216506,0.125 0.5,0 0.216506,-0.125 0.25,-0.433013 0,-0.25 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.216506,-0.125 -0.5,0 -0.216506,0.125 -0.25,0.433013 0,0.25 0.25,0.433013" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.239717,0 0.227984,-0.0740767 0.193935,-0.140902 0.140902,-0.193935 0.0740767,-0.227984 0,-0.239717 -0.0740767,-0.227984 -0.140902,-0.193935 -0.193935,-0.140902 -0.227984,-0.0740767 -0.239717,0 -0.227984,0.0740767 -0.193935,0.140902 -0.140902,0.193935 -0.0740767,0.227984 0,0.239717 0.0740767,0.227984 0.140902,0.193935 0.193935,0.140902 0.227984,0.0740767" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon6Star6"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,0 0.25,-0.433013 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.5,0 -0.25,0.433013 0.25,0.433013" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.216506,0.125 0.5,0 0.216506,-0.125 0.25,-0.433013 0,-0.25 -0.25,-0.433013 -0.216506,-0.125 -0.5,0 -0.216506,0.125 -0.25,0.433013 0,0.25 0.25,0.433013" /></g><g size="1" id="Pgon8Star4"><polygon fill="black" stroke="none" points="0.5,-5.2154e-008 0.353553,-0.353553 -5.2154e-008,-0.5 -0.353553,-0.353553 -0.5,-5.2154e-008 -0.353553,0.353553 -5.2154e-008,0.5 0.353553,0.353553" /><polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="0.162359,0.162359 0.45922,-5.2154e-008 0.162359,-0.162359 -5.2154e-008,-0.45922 -0.162359,-0.162359 -0.45922,-5.2154e-008 -0.162359,0.162359 -5.2154e-008,0.45922" /></g></svg></defs>
</svg>
</div>

</td>
</tr></table>
<script id=myScript>
var SNPsvg = Snap("#mySVG");


var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
var SpriteButtons=[]
function buildSpriteButtons()
{
    var buttonSize=50

    var defs=document.getElementById("spriteDefs")
    var root=defs.firstChild
    var sprites=root.childNodes

    for(var k=0;k<sprites.length;k++)
    {
        var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg")
        svg.setAttribute("overflow","visible")
        svg.setAttribute("x",0)
        svg.setAttribute("y",0)
        svg.setAttribute("width",buttonSize)
        svg.setAttribute("height",buttonSize)
        var mySprite=sprites[k].cloneNode(true)
        mySprite.id='sprite'+k
        mySprite.setAttribute("transform","translate("+buttonSize/2+","+buttonSize/2+")scale("+buttonSize+")")

        var pgons=mySprite.childNodes
        for(var n=0;n<pgons.length;n++)
        {
            var pgon=pgons.item(n)
            pgon.setAttribute("fill",rcolor())
            pgon.setAttribute("stroke",'black')
            pgon.setAttribute("stroke-width",'.025')
            pgon.setAttribute("onclick","animateIcon(evt)")
        }
        SpriteButtons.push(mySprite)
        svg.appendChild(mySprite)
        //---place in a table--
        var row=spriteTable.insertRow(k)
        var svgCell=row.insertCell(0)
        svgCell.style.width="50px"
        svgCell.style.height="50px"
        var button=document.createElement("button")
        svgCell.appendChild(button)

        button.innerHTML=new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)
    }

}

 //---each sprite's polygon onclick---
function animateIcon(evt)
{
    var buttonSize=50
    var mySprite=evt.target.parentNode //---g node---
    var spriteId=mySprite.id
    var animMe=Snap.select("#"+spriteId)

    var rotateRange=360
    var duration=500
   //---animate button---
    Snap.animate(0, 1,
        function(delta) //---setter--
        {
            var angle=rotateRange*delta
            animMe.transform("t("+buttonSize/2+","+buttonSize/2+") s("+buttonSize+") r("+angle+")")
        },
        duration,
        mina.linear
    );

    var symbolSize=30
    SymbolSet.forEach
    (
         function(el)
         {
            var id=el.attr("id")
            if(id.indexOf(spriteId+"_")!=-1)
            {
                var symbolDom=document.getElementById(id)
                var symbolTransform=symbolDom.getAttribute("transform")

                 var txy=el.attr("transform").string.split("t")  //-translate---
                 var trans="t("+txy[1]+")"

                 Snap.animate(0, 1,
                        function(delta) //---setter--
                        {
                            var angle=rotateRange*delta
                            el.transform(trans+" "+"s("+symbolSize+") r("+angle+")")
                        },
                        duration,
                        mina.linear,
                        function()
                        {  //---reset dom element to original transform---
                            symbolDom.setAttribute("transform",symbolTransform)
                        }
                    );
            }
         }
    );

}

//---onload---
var SymbolSet
function addSpriteSymbols()
{
    SymbolSet=Snap.set()
    var symbolSize=30

    var points=randomPoints(100,400,400,symbolSize)

    for(var m = 0; m < points.length; m++ )
    {
        var pnt=points[m]
        var k=rdm(0,SpriteButtons.length-1)

        var mySprite=SpriteButtons[k].cloneNode(true)
        mySprite.removeAttribute("onclick")
        mySprite.id="sprite"+k+"_"+m
        mySprite.setAttribute("transform","translate("+pnt[0]+","+pnt[1]+")scale("+symbolSize+")")

        var pgons=mySprite.childNodes
        for(var n=0;n<pgons.length;n++)
        {
            var pgon=pgons.item(n)
            pgon.removeAttribute("onclick")
        }
        mySVG.appendChild(mySprite)

        var snapSymbol=Snap.select("#sprite"+k+"_"+m)
        SymbolSet.push(snapSymbol)
    }
}

 //---random color---
function rcolor()
{
 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
 var color = '#';
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
 {
     color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
 }
 return color;
}
//---obtain a random whole number from a thru b---
function rdm(a,b)
{
    return a + Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a+1));
}
 function randomPoints(elems,svgWidth,svgHeight,elemSize)
 {
  //--return format:[ [x,y],[x,y],,, ]
  //---Generate  random points---
  function times(n, fn)
  {
   var a = [], i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   a.push(fn(i));
   }
   return a;
  }
  var width=svgWidth-2*elemSize
  var height=svgHeight-2*elemSize

  return  pntsXY = times(elems, function() { return [Math.floor(width * Math.random()) + elemSize, Math.floor(height * Math.random()) + elemSize] });
 }
</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{

   buildSpriteButtons()
        addSpriteSymbols()
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line...

```
var txy=el.attr("transform").string.split("t");
```

Whilst this will work for the first time the animation runs, if you try and click the button mid animation, this will return some garbage to translate, as it's including more stuff than you want like the scale and rotation.

You could possibly get around it with something like...

```
var txy=el.attr("transform").string.split(/(t[^rs]+)/i);
```

So that it doesn't include scales and rotations.

http://jsfiddle.net/js25x4kw/6/

However, you may want to double check what happens to your transform if you still click the button before the animation finishes. There may still be some existing rotation in place for example that is adding on to it, and if you need to reset some variables each time.

Eg I suspect this line...

```
var symbolTransform=symbolDom.getAttribute("transform")
```

May be including a mid animation transform that you reset to at the end, so you may want to store this earlier as a one off (depending on what you want to achieve). Maybe even remove

```
symbolDom.setAttribute("transform",symbolTransform)
```

completely, as I 'think' it works better without it.

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js25x4kw/9/)

Comment: Thanks so much Ian, that did the trick: I removed symbolTransform as you suggested and modified txy. Also, possibly, the SymbolSet, in this circumstance, may not be as precise as an array. I did some testing with an array (using previous symbolTransform value), and the problem did not appear.